# How to use Mock to replace an instance variable without a getter method in Pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I am trying to write a test for a method of class "Process" like this:

```
[main.py]
class Process:
    def run(self):
        p = Print()
        if p.get_foo() is True:
            p.print_hoge()

class Print:
    def __init__(self):
        # I would like to replace this variable to use mock
        self.foo = True

    # I would not like to declare
    def get_foo(self):
        return self.foo
    
    def print_foo(self):
        print(self.foo)
```

Here is my test code.

```
import main
import pytest
from pytest import mark


def test_run(mocker):
    test = mocker.patch("main.Print.print_hoge")
    mocker.patch("main.Print.get_foo", return_value=False)
    p = main.Process()
    p.run()
    test.assert_called()
```

As you know, I change the value True "self.foo" to False use "mocker.patch" for "Print.get_foo".
It would seem like not simple as I replace the value "self.foo" directly like mock an instance variable.
I would not like to declare a method "get_foo".

Is there any better way to meet what I want to do?

Comment: If you don't need to test the real functionality of `Print`, you could just mock `Print` itself and set the value of `foo` in the mock.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Thank you for your comment. I resolved this problem with what you told.